# Is the max attribute, while being used with the date input type restricted only to the yyyy/mm/dd format?

Tags: html

I've tried turning

```
<input type="date" max="1967-12-25">
```

into

```
<input type="date" max="12-25-1967">
```

while the former worked, the latter didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-date-string) requires the format to be `YYYY-MM-DD`. Otherwise it would be the same problem that all date-as-string representations have: *what is the format?* `**-**-YYYY` equally permits the interpretation as `DD-MM-YYYY` and `MM-DD-YYYY`, and any other order has the same problem. You have to stick to some standard, and that is defined as `YYYY-MM-DD`, period.